# Is there a Pokémon that can solo the Elite Four without any restoring items?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I was wondering if it is possible to beat the entire Elite Four in Pokemon X with a single Pokémon (with a specific moveset or strategy) without any health-restoring or PP-restoring items.
Ideally regardless of its nature or IVs. If PP Up is required for some moves or certain EVs that's ok.

Comment: If you grind to level 100, then probably quite a few.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are the [Elite Four trainers](http://www.serebii.net/xy/elitefour.shtml) that you have to defeat:

- *Malva*, **Fire**-type
- *Wikstrom*, **Steel**-type
- *Drasna*, **Dragon**-type
- *Siebold*, **Water**-type
- *Diantha*, mixed team

You need a Pokemon that can learn a **Ground** move for *Steel* and *Fire* types, an **Electric/Grass** move for *Water* type and **Dragon/Ice** move for *Dragon* type.
For the last slot you can choose a **Fire** move (taking advantage from STAB) or a **Rock** move to have more coverage.

One is **Charizard**, and he has access to 2 megaevolutions. I suggest the Y versione due to *Drought* ability (lets you use *Solarbeam* without the charging turn and can increase *Fire* damage).

This is the set for *Mega-CharizardY*:

- Earthquake
- Solarbeam
- Dragon Claw / Dragonpulse (eggmove)
- Flamethrower / Heat Wave
- [Rock Slide / Ancient Power]

Of course you need a well trained Pokemon to do that, at least level 80 I suppose, because you need to oneshot most of them if you don't want to use healing items.

Comment: Coverage is pretty unnecessary if you're just fighting the Elite Four. As long as your moves aren't outright resisted, any strong enough attacker spamming powerful attacks can sweep everything. Even breeding an egg move is more effort than you need to apply.

Comment: @user2357112 Of course, if you use a level 100 Pokemon you can oneshot everything with any powerful attack. I talked about coverage only because Diantha uses a mixed team (i.e. Ice, Grass, Fairy, Flying, Psychic) and they don't fall under the other trainers' types. And Malva's Talonflame is immune to Ground.

Comment: I would also have a recovery attack built in there like Roost or Recover

Answer (score 4):

Palkia seems to be one of the best Pokemon to beat the elite 4 alone. It has got some really good attack stats (120 physical and 150 special) and isn't really slow (100 base stat). I recommend to maximize Special attack and speed with this move set :

- **Spatial Rend** would destroy *Drasna* team (max PP : 8 attacks moves would be sufficient)
- **Earthquake** or **Earthpower**, but I would recommend **Earthquake** in order to be able to make some damage on special defensive tank (like the Diantha M-Gardevoir); this attack would destroy *Malva* and *Wikstrom*, but not all due to double Fly type / Levitate
- **Thunderbolt** for *Siebold's* team and any Flying types (you can use Thunder, but only 70% accuracy could lead to missing an attack)
- **Surf** is a pretty good Water move that would finish *Malva's* team and *Siebold's* Water/Ground type.

**Lustrous Orb** is Palkia's dedicated item, but you can give him **Leftovers** to recover a few HP each turn against each Pokemon that you won't be able to OHKO

Comment: Does downvoter could explain why Palkia isn't suitable against Elite Four? So I could made some change in order to answer better at OP question (saying that I take care about Diantha team isn't a valid explanation, OP didn't mentionned her)

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes, they usually come for new answers on old questions. Your answer is good and well formatted, no reason to downvote. Take an upvote and welcome on Arqade!

Answer (score 2):

Let me introduce you to "Funbro" (Warning: this strategy will lose you any friends you have and requires a *ton* of patience)

1. Acquire Slowbro
2. Give him a Leppa Berry
3. Teach him Recycle, Slack Off, Block, and Heal Pulse (this last move is optional for you)

You now have a permanent stall Pokemon. For your specific situation, you could either just not use Heal Pulse or have him learn any other move. This is how your battles will typically go:

1. Use Block to prevent enemies from switching out or escaping.
2. If your Leppa Berry has been consumed, use Recycle.
3. If you don't think you can survive the next attack (or if you just feel like it), use Slack Off
4. Optionally, use Heal Pulse to keep your opponent from fainting.

Now, you can either stall the enemy Pokemon until they Struggle themselves to death or you could use a damaging move in place of Heal Pulse to take them out.

Comment: I know your question deals only with the Elite Four (and therefore singleplayer), but be warned that Funbro is banned in pretty much any Pokemon tournament.

Comment: Funbro is perfectly acceptable in VGC, which is literally the only official tournament... because it doesn't work in Double Battles - it either gets ignored or double-teamed.

Comment: How is this a viable strategy to beat Elite Four? Slowbro is one of the slowest Pokemon, he gets outspeeded from every enemy and he can't heal himself with Heal Pulse.

Comment: @pinckerman The strategy is explained pretty well. It's an absolutely awful and boring strategy for ANYTHING in game, but it's explained well.

Comment: I don't understand how this would prevent Slowbro from being one-shot.  Both Slowbro and Mega Slowbro only have 80 base special defense and a Dark Pulse/Shadow Ball/Thunderbolt from a powerful enough Pokémon could probably take him down before he could heal.  You could prevent attaction, confusion, or critical hits with his abilities, but not all at once - not to mention paralysis or freezing that would prevent you from healing.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm not saying it's not clear, I'm saying it doesn't make sense for OP's purpose. To set the strategy Slowbro needs at least 2 turns (Block and Slack Off), how is it supposed to resist 2 attacks from every enemy Pokemon? Chase got the point.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann 95/180/80 is a pretty bloody bulky. You could even run something like 252 HP / 252 Sp. Def and tank most anything, especially as Mega Slowbro prevents any critical hits. Something you gotta remember is that most NPC pokemon are very poorly optimized. A level 100 M Slowbro will take little if any damage from most things in the league.

Comment: @SGR But why a bulky set then? A sweeper Pokemon is way better, imho. M-Slowbro will take little damage but he can still be confused, burnt, poisoned, paralyzed.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Assuming the elite 4 information from [here](http://www.serebii.net/xy/elitefour.shtml) is accurate, at level 100, 252hp/252spdef calm mega slowbro will take no more than 30% from any attack in the elite 4 assuming: positive +atk/spa nature, 31 IV atk/spa on attacker, 0 EVs on attacker. Malva's Chandelure and Diantha's Gardevoir can KO you with shadow ball if they get enough spdef drops.

Comment: Also this 'funbro' loses to: toxic, dragon tail/roar/whirlwind, taunt, any set-up move, any move that can drop defenses, volt switch/u-turn... etc

Comment: Commenters (myself included) have missed the fact that you can't use Mega Slowbro and the Leppa Berry/Recycle strat at the same time because mega evolution requires the Pokémon to hold their mega stone.  The infinite stall setup specified in this answer only works with normal Slowbro.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Also Slowbronite is ORAS exclusive and OP is asking for XY Elite Four.

Comment: -1. This is a fun strategy for trolling bad players on ladder, but this is a terrible strategy for ingame. The entire point of funbro is to create a battle that _never_ ends until your opponent forfeits, and ingame trainers will never do that. It's also incredibly boring, especially if you're just fighting NPCs.

Comment: And this would lose the second fight in the elite four due to not having any PP